# Trying to use xautolock to suspend activity after a certain amount of time

Tags: manjaro, i3, suspend, lock, xautolock

I'm using manjaro (5.8.18-1-MANJARO) and the i3 window manager.

I'm trying to lock the screen then suspend activity after given amounts of idle time. I've found that `xautolock` should suit my needs using both the `-locker` and `-killer` flags. My i3 config contains the following :

`exec --no-startup-id xautolock -time 5 -locker blurlock -notify 15 -notifier "notify-send 'Screen will lock in 15 s'" -detectsleep -killtime 60 -killer "systemctl suspend"`

However, this doesn't seem to work:

1. The locker part works fine, but system doesn't suspend after 60 minutes.
2. If I suspend the system manually (I'm using a modified version of the `i3exit` script, the executed command is `xautolock -locknow && systemctl suspend`), then the system suspends *again* shortly after i resumed it. This behavior started very recently, I think after a system update, and I don't think I've changed anything else than the `i3exit` myself in system settings / config. I don't know what could be putting the system to sleep again since I don't have any power-manager activated to my knowledge.

Thanks for your help !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To answer part 1) then add the no-fork option to blurlock as below:

```bsh
exec --no-startup-id xautolock -time 5 -locker 'blurlock -n' -notify 15 -notifier "notify-send 'Screen will lock in 15 s'" -detectsleep -killtime 60 -killer "systemctl suspend"
```

As blurlock is built on top of i3lock this will pass the following option (according to the i3lock [man page](https://linux.die.net/man/1/i3lock)):

> -n, --nofork
> Don't fork after starting.

Which I find rather cryptic, and wouldn't have figured out myself if if not for a similar question on the [Arch forum](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=225583).

Comment: Thanks, this solved part 1, and somehow part 2 is also solved. Maybe I tweaked something else that fixed the thing. Thanks !